# How do you initiate a "refresh" by pulling values from Redux Store?

Tags: reactjs, react-native, redux, state

I have a set of data that pulls updated values correctly from a Saga API (shows correct in console.log()), however it doesn't update the values in the UI when pulling to refresh the page.

I've tried to manually reassign the new updated JSON from the refresh to override the old data, however it's just returning null values

```
   // Scroll View
    <ScrollView
      refreshControl={
        <RefreshControl
          tintColor={'#E4E4E4'}
          refreshing={this.state.refreshing}
          onRefresh={this._onRefresh}
        />
      }
    >
      {exchanges.exchanges.length > 0 &&
        exchanges.exchanges.map((exchange, index) => (
          this.renderExchange(exchange, index)
        ))}
    </ScrollView>




 // Render Exchange 
 renderExchange = (exchange, index) => {
 const { account, exchanges } = this.props
 const { balances, exchangeArray } = this.state
 const { selectedExchange } = exchanges
 const { status, symbolPriceTicker, dayChangeTicker } = 
 selectedExchange
//this.setState({ balances: exchange.balances })
//AlertIOS.alert('I got here')

if (balances.length > 0 && exchangeArray.length > 0) {
  for (let i = 0; i < exchangeArray.length; i++) {
    if (exchange === exchangeArray[i]) {
      for (let j = 0; j < balances.length; j++) {
        console.log('Updated Balances: ' + JSON.stringify(balances[j]))
        console.log('Exchange Balances: ' + JSON.stringify(exchange.balances))
        exchange.balances = balances[j]
        balances.pop()
      }
    }
  }
}

return (
  <View style={screenStyles.container}>
  <ExchangeBox
    balances={exchange.balances}
    displayName={exchange.label}
    symbolPriceTicker={symbolPriceTicker}
    exchangeIndex={index}
    onSend={this.onSend}
  />
  <View style={screenStyles.largerContainer}>
    {symbolPriceTicker && dayChangeTicker && exchange.balances && (
      <ScrollView
        style={screenStyles.walletContainer}
        horizontal={true}
        showsHorizontalScrollIndicator={false}
        decelerationRate={0}
        snapToInterval={100} //your element width
        snapToAlignment={'center'}
      >
        {Object.keys(exchange.balances).map(
          symbol =>
            COIN_INFO[symbol] &&
            symbolPriceTicker[`${symbol}USDT`] && (
              <CoinContainer
                key={symbol}
                symbol={symbol}
                available={exchange.balances[symbol].free}
                price={symbolPriceTicker[`${symbol}USDT`]}
                dayChange={dayChangeTicker[`${symbol}USDT`]}
              />
            ),
        )}
      </ScrollView>
    )}
  </View>
</View>
)
}




fetchData = () => {
  const { exchanges } = this.props
  const { balances, exchangeArray } = this.state
  // Needs to fetch information to refresh
  if (exchanges.exchanges.length > 0) {
    exchanges.exchanges.map((exchange) => (
      balances.push(this.props.getBalances(exchange.balances)),
      exchangeArray.push(exchange)
      //console.log(exchange.balances)
    ))
    this.setState({ refreshing: false })
  } else {
    this.setState({ refreshing: false })
  }
}




componentDidMount() {
  this.fetchData()
}




_onRefresh = () => {
  this.setState({ refreshing: true })
  this.fetchData()
}
```

Is there any way I can successfully reassign these values or is there a better way in doing this refresh?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

your fetchData is not fetching data, I don't understand this method.

But I see that you are changing state incorrectly without using `setState`.

So I just tried to fix it with minimal changes.

```
fetchData = () => {
  const { exchanges } = this.props
  // you need to make new arrays, thats why we are using slice.
  const balances = this.state.balances.slice(); 
  const exchangeArray = this.state.exchangeArray.slice();

  if (exchanges.exchanges.length > 0) {
    exchanges.exchanges.map((exchange) => (
      balances.push(this.props.getBalances(exchange.balances)),
      exchangeArray.push(exchange)
      //console.log(exchange.balances)
    ))
   // we need to update the state using, setState, and passing our 2 arrays.
    this.setState({ refreshing: false, exchangeArray, balances })
  } else {
    this.setState({ refreshing: false })
  }
}
```

Comment: Gotcha, thanks for that! Well currently when I send a transaction, the information doesn't update the balance values in the UI.  I know I'm not making an async call, but when I console.log that information the new balances show, which doesn't make sense as to why the balances don't update.  So I figure if I can reassign the values then it'll fix

Comment: The this.props.getBalances is an action creator I have set up that will fetch the latest values

Comment: @Tom a bit confused, did it work for you? consider marking it as a correct answer if it did

Comment: I rephrased the question, maybe this makes a little more sense as to what I'm asking ->  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55528127/how-do-you-update-some-state-with-a-redux-get-function-values-not-updating-corr

Comment: @Tom okay then close this question if it does not make sense to you.