# How do you update some state with a redux get function? Values not updating correctly on set

Tags: reactjs, redux, redux-saga

I currently am fetching some balances via a redux getBalances method.  When the app initializes it sets 'balances' to the JSON of information, however when I call getBalances again it doesn't re-set the balances (no idea why).

So right now, I'm manually trying to update the balances by calling the getBalances method then setting the result of that to balances, however I'm running into walls.

All I'd like to do is getBalances again and merely set this to balances, however I'm not sure how I'd do this in redux.

```
// Sequence of events (all of these are in different files of course)    

// Action Call
export const getBalances = exchange => 
action(actionTypes.GET_BALANCES.REQUEST, { exchange })

// API Call
export const getBalances = ({ userId, exchange }) =>
API.request(`/wallets/${userId}/${exchange}`, 'GET')
```

Full saga

```
          import { fork, takeEvery, takeLatest, select, put, call, throttle } from 'redux-saga/effects'
          import { NavigationActions } from 'react-navigation'

          import * as actionTypes from '../action-types/exchanges.action-types'
          import * as API from '../api'

          import { storeType } from '../reducers'
          import { async, delay } from './asyncSaga'
          import { asyncAction } from './asyncAction'

          let getBalanceCount = 0

          export function* getBalances(action) {
          getBalanceCount++
          const state: storeType = yield select()
          yield fork(async, action, API.getBalances, {
            exchange: state.exchanges.selectedExchange._id,
            userId: state.auth.userId,
          })
          if (getBalanceCount > 1) {
            getBalanceCount--
            return
          }
          yield delay(10000)
          if (state.auth.token && state.auth.status === 'success')
            yield put({ type: action.type, payload: {} })
          /*
          if (state.auth.token && state.auth.status === 'success' && state.auth.phoneVerified)
            yield put({ type: action.type, payload: {} }) */
          }

          export function* getExchanges(action) {
          const state: storeType = yield select()
          yield fork(async, action, API.getExchanges, { userId: state.auth.userId })
          }

          export function* getExchangesSuccess(action) {
          const state: storeType = yield select()
          if (state.exchanges.exchanges.length > 0) {
            yield put({ type: actionTypes.GET_BALANCES.REQUEST, payload: {} })
          }
          }

          export function* addExchange(action) {
          const state: storeType = yield select()
          yield fork(async, action, API.addExchange, { ...action.payload, userId: state.auth.userId })
          }

          export function* addExchangeSuccess(action) {
          yield put(
            NavigationActions.navigate({
              routeName: 'wallets',
              params: { transition: 'slideToTop' },
            }),
          )
          }

          export function* updatePrices(action) {
          const async = asyncAction(action.type)
          const state = yield select()
          try {
            const res = yield call(API.getSymbolPriceTicker)
            yield put(async.success(res))
          } catch (error) {
            yield put(async.failure(error))
          }
          yield delay(10000)
          if (state.auth.token && state.auth.status === 'success' && state.auth.phoneVerified)
            yield put({ type: action.type, payload: {} })
          }

          export function* updateDaily(action) {
          const async = asyncAction(action.type)
          try {
            const res = yield call(API.getdayChangeTicker)
            yield put(async.success(res))
          } catch (error) {
            yield put(async.failure(error))
          }
          }

          export function* getFriendExchange(action) {
          yield fork(async, action, API.getExchanges, { userId: action.payload.userId })
          }

          export function* selectExchange(action) {
          yield put({ type: actionTypes.GET_BALANCES.REQUEST, payload: {} })
          }

          export function* exchangesSaga() {
          yield takeEvery(actionTypes.GET_SYMBOL_PRICE_TICKER.REQUEST, updatePrices)
          yield takeEvery(actionTypes.GET_DAY_CHANGE_TICKER.REQUEST, updateDaily)
          yield takeLatest(actionTypes.GET_FRIEND_EXCHANGES.REQUEST, getFriendExchange)
          yield takeLatest(actionTypes.GET_BALANCES.REQUEST, getBalances)
          yield takeLatest(actionTypes.GET_EXCHANGES.REQUEST, getExchanges)
          yield takeLatest(actionTypes.GET_EXCHANGES.SUCCESS, getExchangesSuccess)
          yield takeLatest(actionTypes.ADD_EXCHANGE.REQUEST, addExchange)
          yield takeLatest(actionTypes.ADD_EXCHANGE.SUCCESS, addExchangeSuccess)
          yield takeLatest(actionTypes.SELECT_EXCHANGE, selectExchange)
          }
```

Full Exchange Reducer

```
    import { mergeDeepRight } from 'ramda'
    import {
      GET_BALANCES,
      GET_EXCHANGES,
      SELECT_EXCHANGE,
      GET_SYMBOL_PRICE_TICKER,
      GET_DAY_CHANGE_TICKER,
      GET_FRIEND_EXCHANGES,
      ADD_EXCHANGE,
    } from '../action-types/exchanges.action-types'
    import { LOG_OUT, VALIDATE_TOKEN } from '../action-types/login.action-types'
    import { ExchangeService } from '../constants/types'

    // Exchanges Reducer

    export type exchangeState = {
      status: string
      _id: string
      label: string
      displayName: string
      dayChangeTicker: any
      symbolPriceTicker: any
      balances: any,
    }

    export type exchangesState = {
      status: string
      selectedExchange: exchangeState
      addExchange: {
        status: string,
      }
      exchanges: Array<ExchangeService>
      friendExchanges: Array<ExchangeService>,
    }

    const initialExchangeState: exchangeState = {
      status: 'pending',
      _id: '',
      label: '',
      displayName: null,
      dayChangeTicker: {},
      symbolPriceTicker: {},
      balances: {},
    }

    const initialState: exchangesState = {
      status: 'pending',
      selectedExchange: {
        status: 'pending',
        _id: '',
        label: '',
        displayName: null,
        dayChangeTicker: {},
        symbolPriceTicker: {},
        balances: {},
      },
      addExchange: {
        status: 'pending',
      },
      exchanges: [],
      friendExchanges: [],
    }

    export default (state = initialState, action) => {
      switch (action.type) {
        case SELECT_EXCHANGE:
        case GET_SYMBOL_PRICE_TICKER.SUCCESS:
        case GET_DAY_CHANGE_TICKER.SUCCESS:
        case GET_BALANCES.REQUEST:
        case GET_BALANCES.SUCCESS:
        case GET_BALANCES.FAILURE:
          return { ...state, selectedExchange: selectedExchangeReducer(state.selectedExchange, action) }

        case GET_EXCHANGES.REQUEST:
        case GET_FRIEND_EXCHANGES.REQUEST:
          return { ...state, status: 'loading' }

        case GET_EXCHANGES.SUCCESS:
          if (action.payload.exchanges.length > 0) {
            return mergeDeepRight(state, {
              exchanges: action.payload.exchanges,
              selectedExchange: { ...action.payload.exchanges[0] },
              status: 'success',
            })
          }
          return { ...state, status: 'success' }

        case GET_FRIEND_EXCHANGES.SUCCESS:
          return { ...state, friendExchanges: action.payload.exchanges, status: 'success' }

        case GET_EXCHANGES.FAILURE:
        case GET_FRIEND_EXCHANGES.FAILURE:
          return { ...state, message: action.payload.message, status: 'failure' }

        case LOG_OUT.SUCCESS:
        case VALIDATE_TOKEN.FAILURE:
          return initialState

        case ADD_EXCHANGE.REQUEST:
          return { ...state, addExchange: { status: 'loading' } }

        case ADD_EXCHANGE.SUCCESS:
          return { ...state, addExchange: { status: 'success' } }

        case ADD_EXCHANGE.FAILURE:
          return { ...state, addExchange: { status: 'failure' } }

        default:
          return state
      }
    }

    const selectedExchangeReducer = (state = initialExchangeState, action) => {
      switch (action.type) {
        case SELECT_EXCHANGE:
          if (action.payload.exchange) {
            return { ...state, ...action.payload.exchange }
          }
          return initialExchangeState

        case GET_SYMBOL_PRICE_TICKER.SUCCESS:
          const symbolPriceTicker = action.payload.data.data.reduce((result, ticker) => {
            result[ticker.symbol] = ticker.price
            return result
          }, {})
          return { ...state, symbolPriceTicker }

        case GET_DAY_CHANGE_TICKER.SUCCESS:
          const dayChangeTicker = action.payload.data.data.reduce((result, ticker) => {
            result[ticker.symbol] = ticker.priceChangePercent
            return result
          }, {})
          return { ...state, dayChangeTicker }

        // Get selected exchange's balances
        case GET_BALANCES.REQUEST:
          return { ...state, status: 'loading' }

        case GET_BALANCES.SUCCESS:
          return {
            ...state,
            balances: action.payload.balances,
            status: 'success',
          }

        case GET_BALANCES.FAILURE:
          return { ...state, balances: [], message: action.payload.message, status: 'failure' }

        default:
          return state
      }
    }
```

Physical function call (fetchData is my attempt at reassigning exchange.balances...)

```
    // this.props.selectExchange(exchange) just selects the exchange then calls a GET_BALANCES.REQUEST
    fetchData = (exchange) => {
      const { selectedExchange } = this.props.exchanges
      // const { exchanges } = this.props
      // //console.log('TesterTesterTester: ' + JSON.stringify(this.props.selectExchange(exchange)))
      // console.log('Test:' + JSON.stringify(this.props.getBalances(exchange.balances)))
      // let vari = JSON.stringify(this.props.getBalances(exchange.balances))
      // let newVari = JSON.parse(vari.slice(45, vari.length-2))
      // exchange.balances = newVari
      // console.log('Old Values: ' + JSON.stringify(exchange.balances))
      console.log('Testt: ' + JSON.stringify(this.props.selectExchange(exchange.balances1)))
      this.props.selectExchange(exchange.balances1)
      console.log('This exchange after: ' + selectedExchange)
      console.log('This is the balances: '+ JSON.stringify(selectedExchange.balances1))
      exchange.balances = selectedExchange.balances1
      console.log('Another one: ' + JSON.stringify(exchange.balances))
      selectedExchange.balances1 = []

      this.setState({ refreshing: false })
    }

    renderExchange = (exchange, index) => {
      const { refreshing } = this.state
      const { selectedExchange } = this.props.exchanges
      const { symbolPriceTicker, dayChangeTicker } = selectedExchange

      // I'm trying to alter exchange.balances

      if (refreshing) {
        this.fetchData(exchange)
      }

      return (
        <View style={screenStyles.container}>
          <ExchangeBox
            balances={exchange.balances}
            displayName={exchange.label}
            symbolPriceTicker={symbolPriceTicker}
            exchangeIndex={index}
            onSend={this.onSend}
          />
          <View style={screenStyles.largerContainer}>
            {symbolPriceTicker && dayChangeTicker && exchange.balances && (
              <ScrollView
                style={screenStyles.walletContainer}
                horizontal={true}
                showsHorizontalScrollIndicator={false}
                decelerationRate={0}
                snapToInterval={100} //your element width
                snapToAlignment={'center'}
              >
                {Object.keys(exchange.balances).map(
                  symbol =>
                    COIN_INFO[symbol] &&
                    symbolPriceTicker[`${symbol}USDT`] && (
                      <CoinContainer
                        key={symbol}
                        symbol={symbol}
                        available={exchange.balances[symbol].free}
                        price={symbolPriceTicker[`${symbol}USDT`]}
                        dayChange={dayChangeTicker[`${symbol}USDT`]}
                      />
                    ),
                )}
              </ScrollView>
            )}
          </View>
        </View>
      )
    }
```

After messing with this I found that exchange.balances wasn't grabbing values because the .balances was a JSON extension of the JSON of exchange.  I tried making all of the instance of balances elsewhere (like in the reducer balances1) and that didn't help much when trying to update.

Here's another call of balances in types.ts

```
  export type ExchangeService = {
    _id: string
    label: string
    displayName: string
    balances: any,
  }
```

Thank you so much @Dylan for walking through this with me

Comment: is the problem in if statement `state.auth.token && state.auth.status === 'success'` ?

Comment: Could you show how/where you're invoking the `getBalances` saga?  Is it part of a larger saga?  It's difficult to answer this question without knowing how it's being driven.

Comment: @DylanWalker The getBalances saga is called via GET_BALANCES.REQUEST after the getBalances action is called

Comment: Let me clarify: I'm trying to figure out if sagas are being used idomatically here.  With the current code structure, I'd expect that `getBalances` is being run by something like `takeLatest('SOME_ACTION', getBalances)` from a larger saga.  Is this the case?  Are you trying to use the saga as a regular generator?  Are you just calling `getBalances({'SOME_ACTION'})` straight up? What action are you expecting `getBalances` to dispatch via the `put`?  I see a bunch of weird things but I'd like the full picture before I suggest improvements.

Comment: @DylanWalker It's a part of a larger saga.  I just posted the full saga & the full reducer to build full context.  Basically when the app first loads it getsExchanges and after that succeeds it calls getExchangesSuccess which calls the first GET_BALANCES.REQUEST

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As discussed in the comments:

You're slightly overthinking how you're managing your state via `fetchData`. It appears you're attempting to dispatch an action and use the results in the same render cycle, which will have inconsistent results at best using Redux.

Instead, when using Redux with React, you should almost completely rely on Redux to handle your state management.  Your React components should only be used for dispatching Redux actions and displaying incoming data, as per the following data flow:

1. Component dispatches an action to the store.
2. The action is processed by your sagas and reducers to update the state in the store.
3. Redux updates the props being provided to the component via `connect()`.
4. The updated props trigger a re-render of the component.
5. The updated state is now available to the component via `this.props` in your `render()` function on the triggered render cycle.

As this relates to your component, your `fetchData` function would probably be simplified to something like this:

```
fetchData = exchange => {
    this.props.selectExchange(exchange);
    // ...any additional action dispatches required to fetch data.
}
```

If your reducers and sagas are written correctly (which they appear to be), then your Redux state will be updated asynchronously.  When the update is complete, your components props will be updated and a re-render triggered.  Then, in your `render()` function, all data you display from the state should be derived from `this.props`.  By doing this, you largely guarantee that the display is up-to-date:

```
render() {
    const exchange = this.props.selectedExchange;

    return (
        <View style={screenStyles.container}>
            <ExchangeBox
                balances={exchange.balances}
                displayName={exchange.label}
                // ... more props
            />
            //... more components
        </View>
    );
}
```

At this point, your component is setup with a simple and idiomatic Redux data flow.  If you encounter any issues with state updates from this point, you can start looking at your sagas/reducers for issues.

Below is my original answer which talked about a potential issue with the posted sagas, which I'll keep for completeness.

---

Thanks for the clarifying edits.  Took me awhile to understand, because this saga structure is really unusual, but I think I have an idea of what's going on here.  Please correct me if I make any wrong assumptions.

```
yield delay(10000)
if (state.auth.token && state.auth.status === 'success')
    yield put({ type: action.type, payload: {} })
```

I assume the purpose of this is to update the `balances` every 10 seconds once the saga has been initially kicked off.  I'm also assuming you have `getBalancesCount` to limit the number of instances of `getBalances` looping at once.  Lets walk through how this happens:

- Initial dispatch -> `yield takeLatest(actionTypes.GET_BALANCES.REQUEST, getBalances)` kicks off `getBalances`.
- `getBalances` hits `getBalanceCount++`, so `getBalanceCount == 1`
- `getBalances` is repeated, due to `put({ type: action.type, payload: {} })`
- `getBalances` hits `getBalanceCount++`, so `getBalanceCount == 2`
- `getBalances` hits `if (getBalanceCount > 1)`, satisfies the condition, decrements `getBalanceCount` to `1` and exits.

Now, I'm assuming `yield fork(async, action, API.getBalances...)` eventually dispatches `GET_BALANCES.SUCCESS` in `asyncSaga`, so it'll continue to work each time you dispatch `GET_BALANCES.REQUEST` from outside the saga.

You could fix up the logic for `getBalancesCount`.  However, we don't need a counter at all to limit the number of concurrent `getBalances` running at once.  This is already built into `takeLatest`:

> Each time an action is dispatched to the store. And if this action matches `pattern`, `takeLatest` starts a new `saga` task in the background. **If a `saga` task was started previously (on the last action dispatched before the actual action), and if this task is still running, the task will be cancelled**.

(See: https://redux-saga.js.org/docs/api/)

So all you really have to do is remove your custom logic:

```
export function* getBalances(action) {
    const state: storeType = yield select()
    yield fork(async, action, API.getBalances, {
        exchange: state.exchanges.selectedExchange._id,
        userId: state.auth.userId,
    })

    yield delay(10000)
    if (state.auth.token && state.auth.status === 'success')
        yield put({ type: action.type, payload: {} })
    }
}
```

In addition, repeating a saga by dispatching the same action from within the saga is kind of an anti-pattern.  `while(true)` tends to be more idiomatic despite looking strange:

```
export function* getBalances(action) {
    while(true) {
        const state: storeType = yield select()
        yield fork(async, action, API.getBalances, {
            exchange: state.exchanges.selectedExchange._id,
            userId: state.auth.userId,
        })

        yield delay(10000);
        if (!state.auth.token || state.auth.status !== 'success')
           return;
        }
    }
}
```

Though, if you have other things consuming `GET_BALANCES.REQUEST` for some reason, this might not work for you.  In that case, I'd be using separate actions though.  (EDIT: I re-read your reducer, and you're indeed using the action to set a `loading` state.  In this case, your approach is probably fine.)

Comment: I had just found an issue in the code as well if you wouldn't mind taking a look at this as well.  I'll add it to the bottom of the below, I tried messing around with it however it's not yielding the correct action.

Comment: @Tom Two things about your `fetchData`: 1. Are you trying to log the updated state (`console.log('This exchange after: ' + selectedExchange)`) immediately after dispatching an action (`this.props.selectExchange(exchange.balances1)`)?  If so, realize that actions and state updates are asynchronous, and won't be reflected in the same render cycle.  It could be that your state is updating, you're just looking too early.  2. What are you trying to do with these direct assignments (`exchange.balances = selectedExchange.balances1`)?

Comment: I'm trying to have it be where the exchange.balances updates so that way it's reflected correctly in the UI when the user scroll down to call an onRefresh.  How would you structure fetchData?

Comment: @Tom Just rely on Redux.  When you're using Redux, you should have basically zero logic for fetching or updating state in your component.  If you want to trigger a state change from your component, all you have to do is dispatch an action (as you're doing with this.props.selectExchange()).  Your action will hit your sagas and reducers, and update the state in the store.  This will update the props that you've mapped to your component via `connect()`.  This will trigger a re-render, and your updated balances will be available via `this.props.selectedExchange.balances` on the next `render()`.

Comment: That is to say, `fetchData` should simply call any actions which fetch new data in your saga.  In your `render()` function, everything you display should be derived from `this.props` (or `this.state`, if you're storing anything there, which should be limited when using redux).  If you're trying to manually change things apart from using your actions and props, you're defeating the point of redux and making things more difficult.  If you set it up this way, and then its STILL not working, you can start looking at your sagas and reducers for issues.

Comment: Your more recent solution in the chat with selectExchange worked! If you post it as an answer I'll give it the selected answer it deserves! I appreciate all your help, means a lot!

Comment: @Tom Glad to hear things are working out!  Updated my answer to reflect our discussion.  Good luck!